# Buildozer Class not found b'org/renpy/android/PythonActivity'

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

After compiling a [Kivy](https://kivy.org) Application with [Buildozer](https://buildozer.rtfd.io/), it crashes on Android when run

Example:

```
"""
Not my actual code, just an example of the error
"""

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = """
#: import ZBarCam kivy_garden.zbarcam.ZBarCam
#: import notification plyer.notification

ZBarCam:
    id: zbarcam
    on_symbols: [notification.notify(message=symbol.data.decode(), toast=True) for symbol in self.symbols]
"""


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


app = TestApp()
app.run()
```

`buildozer.spec`:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = App

# (str) Package name
package.name = app

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = com.app

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,kv,png

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements =
    python3,
    sqlite3,
    kivy==2.0.0,
    kivymd==0.104.2,
    plyer==2.0.0,
    qrcode==7.1,
    libiconv,
    libzbar,
    pillow==7.0.0,
    pyzbar==0.1.8,
    xcamera==2019.928,
    zbarcam==2020.524,

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/icon.png

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = CAMERA

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Log:

```
2021-07-24 16:31:37.175 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:  Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-07-24 16:31:37.175 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 413, in <module>
2021-07-24 16:31:37.177 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy/app.py", line 949, in run
2021-07-24 16:31:37.178 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy/app.py", line 919, in _run_prepare
2021-07-24 16:31:37.180 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 385, in build
2021-07-24 16:31:37.181 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy/uix/screenmanager.py", line 973, in __init__
2021-07-24 16:31:37.183 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy/uix/floatlayout.py", line 65, in __init__
2021-07-24 16:31:37.184 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 76, in __init__
2021-07-24 16:31:37.187 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 359, in __init__
2021-07-24 16:31:37.189 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 463, in apply_class_lang_rules
2021-07-24 16:31:37.190 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 541, in apply
2021-07-24 16:31:37.192 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 661, in _apply_rule
2021-07-24 16:31:37.193 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 463, in apply_class_lang_rules
2021-07-24 16:31:37.195 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 541, in apply
2021-07-24 16:31:37.196 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 663, in _apply_rule
2021-07-24 16:31:37.198 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 659, in _apply_rule
2021-07-24 16:31:37.200 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy_garden/zbarcam/zbarcam.py", line 31, in __init__
2021-07-24 16:31:37.202 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 306, in load_file
2021-07-24 16:31:37.203 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 373, in load_string
2021-07-24 16:31:37.205 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 402, in __init__
2021-07-24 16:31:37.207 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 508, in parse
2021-07-24 16:31:37.209 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 472, in execute_directives
2021-07-24 16:31:37.210 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy_garden/xcamera/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
2021-07-24 16:31:37.212 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy_garden/xcamera/xcamera.py", line 13, in <module>
2021-07-24 16:31:37.213 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy_garden/xcamera/platform_api.py", line 14, in <module>
2021-07-24 16:31:37.215 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/kivy_garden/xcamera/android_api.py", line 7, in <module>
2021-07-24 16:31:37.216 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "/mnt/c/Users/[user]/IdeaProjects/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/app/jnius/reflect.py", line 208, in autoclass
2021-07-24 16:31:37.218 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:    File "jnius/jnius_export_func.pxi", line 28, in jnius.jnius.find_javaclass
2021-07-24 16:31:37.220 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python:  jnius.jnius.JavaException: Class not found b'org/renpy/android/PythonActivity'
2021-07-24 16:31:37.220 1679-1705/com.app.app I/python: Python for android ended.
```

The app ran completely fine on my computer but shows this error when running on Android. Many solutions I have found involve errors caused by directly interfacing with `pyjnius`, but since I am just using Kivy and Buildozer, they did not solve my issue

Comment: Can you attach a minimum working code that will demonstrate the error? Then it will be easier for programmers to identify the error

Comment: I just added an example. Hopefully this will help to solve the issue

Comment: When you execute code below you get this error - `jnius.jnius.JavaException: Class not found b'org/renpy/android/PythonActivity'`?

Comment: That's the error I'm getting and need help with fixing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for everything to work correctly and the example below to run, you need to perform the following steps:

**On your PC:**

```
sudo apt install -y gettext
```

**buildozer.spec:**

```
requirements =
    android,
    kivy,
    libiconv,
    libzbar,
    Pillow,
    plyer,
    pyzbar,
    zbarcam,
    xcamera
osx.python_version = 3
android.permissions = CAMERA
android.arch = armeabi-v7a
# I recommend to uncomment this arguments in your `.spec` file
p4a.branch = develop
p4a.bootstrap = sdl2
```

Do not forget to run this command before assembling - `buildozer android clean`

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy import platform
from kivy_garden.zbarcam import ZBarCam

from plyer import notification

if platform == 'android':
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission

    request_permissions([Permission.CAMERA])

KV = """
Screen:
    ZBarCam:
        on_symbols: app.notify(self)
"""


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def notify(self, instance):
        kwargs = {'title': "Plyer Notification Example", 'message': 'Message', 'toast': True}
        for symbol in instance.symbols:
            kwargs['message'] = symbol.data.decode()
            notification.notify(**kwargs)


app = TestApp()
app.run()
```

Comment: This gave me a new error: `jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Didn't find class "org.renpy.android.PythonActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.app.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.app.app-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.app.app-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: You do all like in documentation - https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#android-on-ubuntu-20-04-64bit

Comment: Try remove `buildozer.spec`, and set all like in my example. And reinstall buildozer according to documentation.

Comment: As I see you use old [xcamera](https://github.com/kivy-garden/xcamera/blob/065f369557a29e5158f56dff33a9d2484f0969ab/src/kivy_garden/xcamera/android_api.py#L7) in new version it fixed

Comment: No, I am using the most recent version of xcamera and it seems to include the fix. I think the issue is with plyer

Comment: Check `PythonActivity` in `/home/USER/APPFOLDER/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/APP/kivy_garden/xcamera/android_api.py`, because it is about this error that the logs say. If everything is fine there and you did everything the same as I did (built the pocket again, set my arguments to`. spec`), then try reinstalling `plyer` - `git+https://github.com/Neizvestnyj/plyer.git@fix-PythonActivity`. Although everything starts up for me...
**Dont forget** `buildozer android clean`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235479/discussion-between-neizvestnyj-and-somemosa).

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still encounters that problem:

renpy was dropped. You need to change

```
# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity
```

in your buildozer.spec file to:

```
# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
android.entrypoint = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity
```